# How to show the cross section of a 3D MengerMesh?

Tags: graphics3d, animation, fractals

I want to show a gif like this: [Menger Sponge Slices](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MengerSpongeSlices/)

[image: Menger Sponge Slices]

I think I can ues a big `Cuboid` to cut the `MengerMesh`.

```
m3=MengerMesh[2,3]
re=Parallelepiped[{5/3,25/3,5/3}+#,{{-(10/3),-(20/3),20/3},{-(20/3),-(10/3),-(20/3)},{20/3,-(20/3),-(10/3)}}]&;
Manipulate[RegionDifference[m3,re[t]],{t,-2.45,-2.4,0.01}]
```

Oh, that's a really bad idea, a bit slow and don't works under some cases **(bug?)**...

And careful, sometimes it'll crash the frontend...

---

And idea for generating such animation?

Comment: Check out `Show[m3, ClipPlanes -> 
  InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}] ]`